# SF work about scientists letting children play in a crashed alien ship to discover its secrets

Tags: story-identification

Children are allowed to play in a  wrecked alien spaceship to uncover its technology because their imagination is not yet affected by their education.

I remember is the idea that by educating our children, by imposing a way of thinking, we might also limit their possible development.

It's been more than 20 years since I read this for sure. I read it in Romanian, but I don't think it was a Romanian author (but there is a slim chance...).

Comment: Hi there! That's a bit terse at the moment, could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the two most important - what kind of "work" was it, a book, a short story? And when would it have been released? As well as anything else the guide would remind you of, even if seems minor - everything may help in getting you an answer. Cheers :)

Comment: Book, story, comic, movie, TV episode, ..., something else?

Comment: Sorry Jenayah, it's been a long time since I read it and all I remember is the idea that by educating our children, by imposing a way of thinking, we might also limit their possible development.

Comment: No worries _(just for your information you can notify previous commenters you replied to them with an "at" (`@Jenayah it's been a long time...`). This way they'll get an inbox notifcation with your newest comment)_. Back to the story-ID; how long is "a long time"? 20 years? 50? And do you have any recollection of it being rather a short story, a standalone novel, a trilogy? Did you read it in English, was it a trasnlation? Please refer to the guide above - you'd be surprised what kind of memories it can trigger :)

Comment: @Jenayah It's been more than 20 years for sure, I read it in Romanian, but I don't think it was a Romanian author ( but there is a slim chance...)